# UILabel not showing if variable has a value

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a label (in my secondVC) which is displaying a segued Double from the firstVC. In the secondVCs viewDidLoad I am printing the `passedDouble` and it is printing the correct amount, so I know my Double is being segued correctly. My `UILabel` is in the secondVC and only shows an amount if the `passedDouble` = 0.0.

SecondViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

var passedDouble = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("testing for a value \(passedDouble)")
    totalLabel.text = String("\(passedDouble)")
}
```

If the passed value is 12.2 for example, it prints this

> testing for a value 12.2

But the label completely disappears from view.

If the passed value is 0.0 however, it prints

> testing for a value 0.0

and the label shows 0.0

In the storyboard I have left the labels standard text as Label. So, I know the label is connected properly as it's text changes **IF** the value is nil.

**EDIT**: Code for the firstVC where I am assigning the value

```
var totalPrice: Double = Double()

@IBAction func basketAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for cost in priceDictionaryToBeSent {
        totalPrice += Double(cost)!
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "basket", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "basket" {
        if let basketVC = segue.destination as? BasketViewController {
            basketVC.passedDouble = totalPrice
            //This is sending the correct price
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `passedDouble`? Are you sure you're not hiding the label programmatically? Is label's `isHidden` property `false`?

Comment: Could you show us the code where you are passing the value ?

Comment: I assign the value in a `prepareForSegue` in the `FirstViewController` and I know that a value **Is** being sent because when I print the doublePassed, it shows up perfectly, but when I put it in the label, it disappears. Whereas if the passedDouble is 0.0, the label shows up as 0.0.

Comment: can you show constraints of the lbl

Comment: I've updated my post with code from firstVC :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that in `prepare(for:sender:)` the `basketVC`'s `view` is already loaded, so its `viewDidLoad` got called before you are setting `basketVC.passedDouble = totalPrice`.

I would rather use setter to update the label everytime the `passedDouble` gets updated. Change the `BasketViewController` code to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

var passedDouble = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        self.totalLabel?.text = "\(passedDouble)"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // no need to set totalLabel.text here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've added my answer following what you said about the view already being loaded. Moved the code to `viewDidAppear`. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Milan Nosáľ for saying the view could've already loaded, indeed it had, so I moved the code from `viewDidLoad` in my `BasketViewController` to `viewDidAppear` as seen below:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: true) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    print("testing for total price £\(passedDouble)")
    totalLabel.text = "Total price £\(passedDouble)"
}
```